# ipod wifi speed simulation (e.b. 3G)

Tags: ios, wifi, ipod-touch

Is there a possibility to simulate throttle the download to the speed of
GPRS, 3G and so on (cellular connection) while I am connected with an Ipod
Touch (IOS 4.2/4 Generation) to the wifi?

What I want is to get a feeling of the duration when I am loading e.g. some
images or xml files from a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're after, but you can do this on your Mac and test in the simulator.

Open the terminal and enter:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 15KByte/s
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80
```

This throttles your connection to 15KB/s - which is approximately 3G.

Testing in the simulator will now be like using 3G.

To put your connection back to normal, you can enter:

```
sudo ipfw delete 1
```

I hope this helps!